# Firebase Notification is not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to learn android programming from stackoverflow and github,

i download this source from:

https://github.com/PiracyIzSed/HospitalApplication

open in in android studio and set the firebase, running it in Memu and my phone,
appointment is working, but notification is not showing.

Please help me how to make this notification when appointment status being changed.

Thanks.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
package com.android.hospitalapplication.UtilityAndNetworkingClasses;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.hospitalapplication.Activities.AppointmentReceiptActivity;
import com.android.hospitalapplication.Activities.Doctor.DoctorActivity;
import com.android.hospitalapplication.Activities.Patient.AppointmentStatusActivity;
import com.android.hospitalapplication.Activities.Patient.PatientActivity;
import com.android.hospitalapplication.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

   /**
 * Created by Gaurav on 31-12-2017.
 */

public class FirebaseNotificationsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d("payload :", "" + remoteMessage.getData());

    String titleNotif = remoteMessage.getData().get("title_notif");
    String contentNotif = remoteMessage.getData().get("body_notif");
    String from = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
    String typeNotif = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");

    if(typeNotif.equals("request")){
    Intent i  = new Intent(this, DoctorActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("notif_frag","new_req");
    PendingIntent resultingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    createNotification(titleNotif,contentNotif,resultingIntent);

    }
    else if(typeNotif.equals("confirmed")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppointmentReceiptActivity.class);
        String docId = from;
        String patId = remoteMessage.getData().get("to_user_id");
        i.putExtra("doc_id",docId);
        i.putExtra("pat_id",patId);
        PendingIntent resultingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        createNotification(titleNotif,contentNotif,resultingIntent);
    }
    else if(typeNotif.equals("rescheduled")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppointmentReceiptActivity.class);
        String docId = from;
        String patId = remoteMessage.getData().get("to_user_id");
        i.putExtra("doc_id",docId);
        i.putExtra("pat_id",patId);
        PendingIntent resultingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        createNotification(titleNotif,contentNotif,resultingIntent);
    }
    else if(typeNotif.equals("follow")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppointmentReceiptActivity.class);
        String docId = from;
        String patId = remoteMessage.getData().get("to_user_id");
        i.putExtra("doc_id",docId);
        i.putExtra("pat_id",patId);
        PendingIntent resultingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        createNotification(titleNotif,contentNotif,resultingIntent);
    }
    else if(typeNotif.equals("declined")){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AppointmentStatusActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        createNotification(titleNotif,contentNotif,resultingIntent);
    }



}

private void createNotification(String titleNotif, String contentNotif, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent) {

    Notification notification = new Notification();

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(notification.defaults);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(titleNotif)
            .setContentText(contentNotif)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{50, 350, 200, 350, 200})
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

}

public void addReminder(final String docID, final String patId){


    DatabaseReference dbrefUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(docID);
    dbrefUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

            DatabaseReference dbrefApt = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Appointments").child(docID).child(patId);

            dbrefApt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String date = dataSnapshot.child("apt_date").getValue().toString();
                    String time = dataSnapshot.child("apt_time").getValue().toString();
                    long eventTime = 0;
                    try {
                        eventTime = getTimeInMillis(date+" "+time);
                        Log.d("time in mils :",""+eventTime);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                    time =df.format(time);
                    String s[] = time.split(":");
                    int hr = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
                    int min = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                    NotificationScheduler.setReminder(getApplicationContext(), PatientActivity.class,hr,min);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

//this means reminder is added

}

public long getTimeInMillis(String date) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    long millis;

    Date d = sdf.parse(date);
    millis= d.getTime();
    Log.d("date , millis:",date+" "+millis);
    return millis;
}
}
```

Comment: Not an area I've done a lot on but Is your phone registered with Firebase?

Comment: To start, print the "remotemessage" to console as a string so that you confirm whether the problem is not receiving the notification or not showing it

Comment: i try to print the "remotemessage" to console as a string and is not receiving